How does a child class use the KeyBindings of its parent?
I'm having trouble dealing with key bindings for an extending class. I've defined the bindings for the parent class, which reacts as expected, but the child class never seems to detect any key pressed.
The parent class was tested on its own, it reacts to key events as expected.
class GeneralPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
    public GeneralPanel(){    
        getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("S"), "doSomething");
        getActionMap().put("doSomething",
                new DoSomethingAction());
    }
    // other stuff, including mouseMoved and the like, and paintComponent
}

So when I press S, it calls the specified function.
Now I need to extend that class to a concrete panel that actually displays stuff
class SpecificPanel extends GeneralPanel implements MouseListener{
    // other stuff, including mouseMoved and the like, and paintComponent
}

That class never reacts to any of the keys specified in the parent class.

Why does class SpecificPanel also implement MouseListener if it extends class GeneralPanel (which already implements MouseListener) ?

@Abra it shouldn't, it did because I wrote SpecificPanel first. It is now removed.

Fixed: when the component is not in focus, calling '''getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)''' makes the component react as expected.

Found the solution: the component is not in focus but its parent window is; calling
'''getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)'''
makes the component react as expected.

Yes, read the Swing  tutorial on Key Bindings for the 3 types of bindings.
